# Connecting to GameWisp Singularity using WebSocket4Net results in failed handshake? C#

Tags: c#, webclient, handshake, websocket4net

I am trying to connect a client to the GameWisp Realtime API using WebSocket4Net. My connection code looks like this:

```
public void Connect(string OAuth)
    {
        LoginData login = new LoginData(GAMEWISP_CLIENT_ID, GAMEWISP_CLIENT_SECRET);

        Console.WriteLine("OAtuh = " + OAuth);
        socket = new Client("https://singularity.gamewisp.com");
        Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect");
        try
        {
            socket.Connect();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("awaiting response");
        socket.On("connect", (data) =>
         {
             Console.WriteLine(data);
             socket.Emit("authenticate", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login));
         });

        socket.On("authenticated",(data) =>    {Console.WriteLine(data);});
    }
```

But uppon running this code I get the following console output:

```
OAtuh = abc
Trying to connect
Error Event: Error initializing handshake with https://singularity.gamewisp.com/
System.Exception: Eine Ausnahme vom Typ "System.Exception" wurde ausgelöst.
awaiting response
```

I understand, that if the handshake fails no connection will be established, and therefor I wont be recieving the 'connect' event.

But how can I fix this to make the handshake work, or even just get more information about what exactly went wrong?

**Edit:**
After doing some research I have discovered, that WebSocket4Net supports the 'socket.io version 0.9.x' but if I am not mistakend I would require 'v1.2.x' if I go by the example given on the GameWisp website:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    ...
```

So now I have to find a different approach. I could use a hint as to how to establish a connection, as well as sending and recieving data.